# SOAP API addComment always sends Email

Tags: email, soap

I am using the SOAP API to interact with a Magento 1.7.0.2 installation. 
I use the SOAP V2 method salesOrder.addComment to change the status of an existing sales order.

I call the method with all params (sessionid, orderIncrementId, status, comment, notify). I set the param 'notify' to false. But this seems to have no effect. After the call the status of my sales order has changed, I can see the comment in the salesorder comment section and I also see the additional information "Customer Not Notified". 
But Magento sends an email anyway!

Why did that happen? Is this an expected behavior because I am changing the state of the sales order?
How can I avoid this behavior that magento sends an email to the customer even if I set the notify flag to false?

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> "I call the method with all params (sessionid, orderIncrementId, status, comment, notify). I set the param 'notify' to **false**. But this seems to have no effect."

You should set the param 'notify' to '0', not to false.